# how to change the world directory in a minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, macos

Is there a way to change the world directory of the minecraft server (java edition) such as putting "Library / Application Support / minecraft / saves / New world" in the server.properties file? I'm using Mac OsX by the way, or can you create a shortcut or something like that? The reason I want to do this is because I have a world that I play in single player, but sometimes I play that same world in multiplayer, and I have to make a copy of my world, to the server directory when I want to play with friends and I have to make a copy of the world in the directory of the game when I want to play alone, I don't want to use the server to play alone, I think resource consuming I want to use the same world in single player and multiplayer server

Comment: There's a `level-name` property, maybe that can use relative or even absolute paths as well. The German Minecraft wiki at least states that using sub-folders is possible, so maybe using `..` to go up a level could as well.

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer on [Changing Path of Server World - Minecraft Forum](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/server-support-and/1931398-changing-path-of-server-world):

> All you have to do is point it to the folder in the server.properties under "level-name," but it has to be a relative path. For example, I have a Test Server in a folder on my Desktop:
>
> ```
> level-name=../../AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/saves/New World
> ```
>
> "../" will go back a directory, if you're unfamiliar with this sort of thing

I use this on Mac:

```
level-name=../../Library/Application Support/minecraft/saves/World Name
```

because the server directory is on a folder on my desktop so I use double `../../` to go back to the main user directory.

Comment: Good to know. I guess I'll use that in the future for all my worlds that should sometimes run on servers.